# How to Eclipse Maven Project Wicket-Spring-JPA-Hibernate

Tags: java, eclipse, m2eclipse, archetypes

I want to create a Maven Project in eclipse using m2eclipse plugin, which will include Wicket, Spring, JPA and Hibernate.

What is the simplest way to do it? Which Archetype should I chose?

Thanks.

Comment: checkout [this SO question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370999/wicket-spring-jpa-hibernate-tutorial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know the wicket-spring-hibernate-quickstart archetype?

http://blog.iprofs.nl/2011/02/15/a-maven-quickstart-on-wicket-spring-and-hibernate/

You could use this a starting point and then modify the created files as needed, e.g. to upgrade the various frameworks to later versions.

But if you just want to  create a simple web application, you could also as well just go without an archetype. When you create the new Maven project in m2eclipse, just select the "Create simple project (skip archetype selection) option and create a simple Maven project with packaging type "war". After that, create the web.xml in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF and add all the needed dependencies like Wicket, Spring, Hibernate to the pom.xml. Creating the Maven project like that without the magic of an archetype may take a little (though it shouldn't be that much) more time, but you know then that your project is really set up in the way you need.